# Whats the difference between using Hash scrolling and scrolltop?

Tags: jquery

I was looking into smooth scrolling for my nav bar and a friend suggested "hash targeting" , ive never heard of this and i was wondering if you guys could point me in the right direction.

My current code

```
$(function() {
$('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1200, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The code my friend sent me

```
$('a.scrollto').click(function(e){
    $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash, {gap:{y:-80}});
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using the scrollTo plugin?

Comment: `this.hash` on an anchor tag will return it's *href attribute*. Your friend however seems to be using a scroll plugin.

Comment: the second one uses scrollTo the first one doesnt. 

Spokey which one is a better solution?

Comment: Ok from that i understand the second one returns the attribute , so when i click on it ie the about link
    <a href="#about">About</a>

 it will return. #about

Comment: Depending on how complex your scrolling is going to be (I am not sure about browser support or smoothness in each browser) the plugin should give more advantages. If you are looking for a simple scroll-to function you don't need to include a whole plugin to achieve that.

Comment: I'm a little apprehensive as i have no idea what {gap:{y:-80}} is.